# JS/jQuery - blur() not firing when user hits "Enter"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, blur

I have a form field that I'd like to munge a little before the user submits the form.
Specifically, it's a location field, and I need to check whether they've added the state abbreviation. If not, I add it.

I'm watching for blur() so i can see when the user's tabbed or clicked out of the field:

```
  $('#views-exposed-form-libraries-map-page-1 .form-item-field-geofield-distance-origin input').blur(function(){
// do stuff
});
```

`
This works fine when the user clicks the submit button or tabs out of the input.
However when the user hits "enter" or "return" to submit the form, the function doesn't run - I'm guessing because there's no blur event.

Is there some other way to snag the input's value and edit it when the user hits "enter" or "return"?

Comment: Trigger this event on submit, `$('form').submit( function(){ $('#views-exposed-form-libraries-map-page-1 .form-item-field-geofield-distance-origin input').trigger('blur') })`

Comment: Thanks to all who posted. I wound up doing this:   
` $('#views-exposed-form-libraries-map-page-1').submit(function(e){
     $('#views-exposed-form-libraries-map-page-1 .form-item-field-geofield-distance-origin input').trigger('blur');
}); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a `.submit` callback as well/instead, this will be called before the actual form submits and you can cancel the submission if needed

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){
   //check/do stuff here before submit
   //use e.preventDefault() or return false to stop submission if needed.
});
```

[JQuery .submit Doc](http://api.jquery.com/submit)

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `.submit()` that trigger `.blur()` on focused element like that :

```
$('form').submit(function(){
     $(':focus').trigger('blur');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
     if(event.keyCode == 13) {
       $(':focus').trigger('blur');
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
     }
   });
```

Comment: Please provide some detail on the answer